# Avoid hardcoding in URLs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

**GeneralUtils**

```
public class GeneralUtils {    

    public static String getUrlWithId(String urlsPartStr) {
        // Get a relative URL like /delete/{id} .
        String result = String.format("%s/{id}", urlsPartStr);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**UrlsParts**

```
public class UrlsParts {   

    public static final String delete = "/delete";

    public static final String deleteById = GeneralUtils.getUrlWithId(delete);

}
```

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping(UrlsParts.deleteById)
public String delete(@PathVariable Integer id,
                     Model model) {
    authorRepository.deleteById(id);

    return "redirect:" + Urls.AUTHORS_LIST.getHref();
}
```

[image]

**Problem**

I'd like somehow avoid hardcoding in URLs. But I seem to have failed. why it is not constant is a mystery to me. But anyway, this doesn't seem to work.

There are a lot of entities in the project. And for each I'll organize CRUD operations. Hardcoding will be violation of DRY principle.

How can I avoid hardcoding in this case?

Comment: > "why it is not constant is a mystery to me" - you call a method. That's not a constant. Doesn't matter what you do in that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess "PathVariable" meets your requirement.

e.g.

change

```
    @PostMapping(UrlsParts.deleteById)
```

to

```
    @PostMapping("/delete/{id}")
```

Comment: It is hardcoding. This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: `@DeleteMapping("/{id}")`